# can't figure out the sizeof(long double) in C is 16 bytes or 10 bytes

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, sizeof, long-double

Although there are some answers are on this websites, I still can't figure out the meaning of `sizeof(long double)`. Why is the output of printing `var3` is `3.141592653589793115998`?

When I try to execute codes from another person, it runs different from another person. Could somebody help me to solve this problem?

My testing codes:

```
float var1 =3.1415926535897932;
double var2=3.1415926535897932;
long double var3 =3.141592653589793213456;


printf("%d\n",sizeof(float));


printf("%d\n",sizeof(double));

printf("%d\n",sizeof(long double));

printf("%.16f\n",var1);
printf("%.16f\n",var2);
printf("%.21Lf\n",var3);
```

output of my testing codes:

```
4
8
16
3.1415927410125732
3.1415926535897931
3.141592653589793115998
```

Codes are the same with another person, but the output from another person is:

```
4
8
12
3.1415927410125732
3.1415926535897931
3.141592741012573213359
```

Could somebody tell me why the output of us are different?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your code to the question. Don't force the readers to follow external links. Also please do not post text as pictures. Include is as text instead.

Comment: With the GNU C Compiler, long double is 80-bit extended precision on x86 processors regardless of the physical storage used for the type (which can be either 96 or 128 bits),[10] On some other architectures, long double can be double-double (e.g. on PowerPC[11][12][13]) or 128-bit quadruple precision (e.g. on SPARC[14]). As of gcc 4.3, a quadruple precision is also supported on x86, but as the nonstandard type __float128 rather than long double.[15] [[More info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double)]

Comment: Please look at all the images which are 'this is my testing codes', ' this is the output of my testing codes' and 'this is the codes and output from another person' if you are gonna help. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidRanieri So, can you tell me what can I do if I want the output of sizeof(long double) is 10 bytes? Is that I should not use the GNU C Compiler? Or something that you can suggest to me? Thank you!

Comment: _Is that I should not use the GNU C Compiler?_ What is your problem? Do you need more precision than the provided by some implementation? We often work with epsilons to deal with those kind of issues (`LDBL_EPSILON` in `float.h`), take a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: (a) The output is different because you and the other person executed the program in different C implementations, and the C standard does not require C implementations to behave identically. They may vary in the sizes and formats used for `long double` and other types and in the quality of conversions between floating-point and decimal (as in `printf`). That said, it does look like the other’s implementation may be low quality in its `long double` formatting or format. (b) Your question “Why is the output of printing var3 is 3.141592653589793115998?” is unclear. That is the output because…

Comment: … that is the result one gets from rounding the `long double` value to 21 decimal digits after the decimal point. What else would you expect? Are you unclear on how the source text `3.141592653589793213456` was converted to `long double`, which involves rounding (adjusting) to fit in the `long double` format? (c) When printing the result of `sizeof`, use `%zu`, not `%d`. `%zu` is for formatting `size_t` types, which `sizeof` produces. `%d` is for `int`. (d) FYI, 3.141592653589793213456 is off from the correct value of π, which is closer to 3.1415926535897932384626433.

Answer (score 0):

### Floating point numbers -inside our computers- are *not* mathematical [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number).

They have lots of counter-intuitive properties (e.g. `(1.0-x) + x` in your C code can be different of 1....). For more, read the [floating-point-gui.de](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Be also aware that a number is not its representation in digits. For example, most of your examples are approximations of [the number π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) (which, intuitively speaking, has an infinite number of digits or bits, since it is a [trancendental number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number), as proven by [Évariste Galois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89variste_Galois) and [Niels Abel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Henrik_Abel)). The [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) is related.

> I still can't figure out the meaning of `sizeof(long double)`.

It is the implementation specific ratio of the number of [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) (or [octets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing))) in a `long double`  [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) vs the number of bytes in a `char` automatic variable.

The C11 standard (read [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) and see [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)) does allow an implementation to have `sizeof(long double)` being, like `sizeof(char)`, equal to 1. I cannot name such an implementation, but it might be (theoretically) the case on some weird computer architectures (e.g. some [DSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor)).

> Could somebody tell me why the output of us are different?

#### What make you think they could be equal?

Practically speaking, floating point numbers are often [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). But on IBM mainframes (e.g. [z/Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Z)) or on [VAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAX)es they are *not*.

> ```
> float var1 =3.1415926535897932;
> double var2 =3.1415926535897932;
> ```

Be aware that it could be possible to have a C implementation where `(double)var1 != var2` or where `var1 != (float)var2`  after executing these above instructions.

If you need more precision that what `long double` achieve on your particular C implementation (e.g. your recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, which could be a [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler)), consider using some [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library such as [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/).

I recommend *carefully* reading the documentation of [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), and of every [other function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) that you are using from your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library). I also suggest to read the documentation of your C compiler.

You might be interested by [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools such as [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). Read also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report.

If your C compiler is a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and learn how to use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger.

Answer (score 0):

> Could somebody tell me why the output of us are different?

C allows different compilers/implementations to use different floating point encoding and handle evaluations in slightly different ways.

**Precision**

The difference in `sizeof` hint that the 2 implementations may employ different precision. Yet the difference could be due to *padding*,  In this case, extra bytes added to preserve an alignment for performance reasons.

A better precision assessment is to print epsilon: the difference between 1.0 and the next larger value of the type.

```
#include <float.h>

printf("%e %e %Le\n", FLT_EPSILON, DBL_EPSILON, LDBL_EPSILON);
```

Sample result

```
1.192093e-07 2.220446e-16 1.084202e-19
```

**`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`**

When this is 0, floating point types evaluate to that type.  With other values like 2, floating point evaluate using wider types and only in the end save the result to the target type.

```
printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD %d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
```

Two of several possible values indicated below:

> `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`
> 0 evaluate all operations and constants just to the range and precision of the type;
> 2 evaluate all operations and constants to the range and precision of the `long double` type.

Notice the constants `3.1415926535897932, 3.141592653589793213456` are both normally `double` constants. Neither has an `L` suffix that would make the `long double`.   Both have the *same* double value of `3.1415926535897931...` and `val2`, `val3` should get the same value.  Yet with `FLT_EVAL_METHOD==2`, constants can evaluated as a `long double` and that is certainly what happened in "the output from another person" code.

Print `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to see that difference.